# How to prevent character from rotating when moving at an angle to an incline

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, game-development

You can see the problem when moving at an angle to the collider: https://8observer8.github.io/webgl10-js/lighthouse-oimophysics-webgl-js/

[image]

I use OimoPhysics but there is no such tag. This is a task common to all physics engines. There is a ball that slides down an inclined surface. It will rotate around an axis pointing upwards in the direction of greatest friction. It can only rotate around the upward axis, rotations around the other axes are frozen.

I created the issue on OimoPhysics GitHub page: https://github.com/saharan/OimoPhysics/issues/65

Another issue on Cannon ES GitHub page with source code in Three.js: https://github.com/pmndrs/cannon-es/issues/183

- PlayCode: https://playcode.io/1507281

[image]

But Ammo.js doesn't have this problem. I just replaced OimoPhysics with Ammo.js and the problem went away: https://8observer8.github.io/webgl10-js/lighthouse-ammo-webgl-js/

[image]

Ammo.js works for bigger angle (42 degrees) too:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's highly unlikely you'll get an answer here as it's specific to the physics engine, your best bet is to contact the developer(s) of the engine ie through a github issue.

Comment: I thought this issue must be very popular. Surely many people have made a first-person controller on this physics engine and have already encountered this problem. This should be the first problem that everyone has to face.

Comment: This is a task common to all physics engines. There is a ball that slides down an inclined surface. It will rotate around an axis pointing upwards in the direction of greatest friction. It can only rotate around the upward axis, rotations around the other axes are frozen.

Comment: Perhpas something for [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. You need to set the rotation factor to (0, 0, 0) when W and S were pressed, and to (0, 1, 0) when A and D were pressed.

Example on OimoPhysics and Three.js: https://playcode.io/1508199

```js
            if (input === "u") {
                /* ... */
                playerBody.setRotationFactor(new OIMO.Vec3(0, 0, 0));
            }

            if (input === "d") {
                /* ... */
                playerBody.setRotationFactor(new OIMO.Vec3(0, 0, 0));
            }

            if (input === "l") {
                /* ... */
                playerBody.setRotationFactor(new OIMO.Vec3(0, 1, 0));
            }

            if (input === "r") {
                /* ... */
                playerBody.setRotationFactor(new OIMO.Vec3(0, 1, 0));
            }
```

[image]